# CoreData - количество элементов в Storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, coredata

Помогите разобраться c `CoreData` - необходимо получить количество позиций в файле хранилища `sqlite`.
Реализовал такой метод - возвращает нули.

```
-(NSInteger) getStorageElementCount {

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TMEmployee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:description];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

self.fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchController.delegate = self;

return  [[self.fetchController fetchedObjects] count];
}
```

До этого делал без `NSFetchedResultsController` - наоборот -возвращал количество которое я так понимаю в контексте а не в хранилище

```
return [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] count];
```

Comment: я так понимаю, после того как вы создали `fetchRequest`, вам надо еще `performFetch:` вызвать, чтоб результаты получить (чисто из документации, сам не пробовал)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Практическая часть

Как совершенно верно прокомментировал Max Mikheyenko, FRC получает объекты после `-performFetch`.

Однако для того, чтобы единоразово получить количество объектов, использование FRC излишне. Достаточно сделать, например, так:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TMEmployee"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %@", @(TMEmployeeKind)];

NSError *error;
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Предикат не надо указывать, если нужно получить количество всех объектов сущности `TMEmployee`.

Также хочу отметить, что `sortDescriptors` тут по очевидным причинам не нужны.

---

## Теоретическая часть

В общих чертах обозначу основную идеологию `Core Data`.

#### Что это вообще такое

Задача, выполняемая `Core Data` – управление данными приложения. Тут библиотека даёт нам возможность балансировать между несколькими противоречивыми требованиями:

- Быстрый доступ к данным.
- Удобство работы.
- Низкий профиль памяти.

Нефициальное определение `Core Data` – система управления объектным графом с балеринами и шахматами. То-есть система держит объекты и связи между ними, и обеспечивает приятные полезности вроде ленивой подгрузки данных и автоматического оповещения об изменениях в объектах. Полный список возможностей [тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html).

#### Почему это стоит использовать

Вкратце – потому, что попытавшись основать свою модель данных на чистом `SQLite`, например, при дальнейшем масштабировании приложения и увеличения количества данных мы, в конце концов, обнаружим, что пишем свою `Core Data`. А в ней уже решены, например:

- [Faulting и Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html). По-умолчанию при выполнении запроса объект подгружается в контекст в виде легковесной "заглушки". При обращении к какому-либо его свойству, `Core Data` наполнит этот объект данными. Такая заглушка называется `fault`, а процесс подгрузки в него данных – `faulting`. Собственно `fault` – это просто возможное состояние объекта класса `NSManagedObject`. Он, кстати, уникален. Каждый запрос к контексту, результаты которого содержат какой-то определённый объект, вернёт указатель на один и тот-же экземпляр объекта – что позволяет избежать дублирования данных в памяти.
- [Batching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize). Результаты запроса могут подгружаться пакетно, по 50 штук, например. Очень удобно для крупных наборов данных, про которые точно известно, что они будут отображаться последовательно, как, например, при прокрутке таблицы. Когда надо будет показать 51-ю строчку, и у делегата `UITableView` будет вызван метод `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, для получения данных 51-го объекта делегат выполнит `DBPerson *person = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];`, и `Core Data` сама запросит следующий пакет. Включается одной строчкой `request.fetchBatchSize = 50;`.
- Удобный доступ к свойствам и связям объектов. После генерации классов сущностей (Editor / Create NSManagedObject subclass…) к свойствам объектов `Core Data` можно обращаться привычным образом:

  ```
  DBDepartment *department = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  DBPerson *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DBPerson" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  person.nameLast   = @"Добчинский";
  person.nameFirst  = @"Пётр";
  person.nameMiddle = @"Иванович";
  person.department = department;
  ```

Библиотека имеет довольно давнюю историю, уходя корнями в [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Objects_Framework) NeXTа, и за свою более чем десятилетнюю историю очень хорошо оттестирована. Что не исключает, конечно, наличия в ней почти столь же древних [глюков](http://mikeabdullah.net/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html).

#### Что такое "стэк"

Это совокупность объектов, управляющих слоем данных в `Core Data`. Например, вот такая:

```
[NSPersistentStore] ↞ [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator] ↠ [NSManagedObjectContext]
         ↓                          ↑
   [SQLite file]          [NSManagedObjectModel]
```

Наиболее известный пример стэка можно посмотреть, создав в Xcode новый проект с включённой галкой "Use Core Data", он будет в классе `AppDelegate`.

***Контекст***

Взаимодействие приложения с данными ведётся через [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html). В самом распространённом случае применения, `mainContext` – это текущее состояние данных приложения, то, к чему привязан интерфейс, то, что видит пользователь. Эти данные можно изменять, добавляя или удаляя объекты, меняя их свойства и устанавливая или разрывая между ними связи в соответствии с действиями пользователя, или, например, при получении данных от веб-сервиса. Все эти изменения находятся в памяти контекста и могут быть синхронно отображены в интерфейсе. При необходимости эти изменения можно сохранить так, чтобы текущее состояние данных пережило прекращение выполнения приложения или выключение устройства. Содержание контекста не обязательно эквивалентно полному графу данных приложения. В контекст подгружаются только те объекты, которые были прямо или косвенно запрошены, с использованием `FRC`, `-executeFetchRequest:error:`, `-objectWithID:` и т.п. Объекты `NSManagedObjectContext` очень дёшевы в создании, их не следует бояться создавать и освобождать для каких-либо промежуточных вычислений.

Источником данных для контекста может выступать или `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, или родительский контекст.

***Модель***

[`NSManagedObjectModel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/index.html) описывает структуру данных приложения: типы объектов, их свойства и их связи. Может также содержать некоторую другую информацию – конфигурации и версии моделей. Обычно модель создаётся визуально, в Xcodовском Core Data Model Editor, но можно и программно.

***Хранилище***

[`NSPersistentStore`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPersistentStore_Class/) отвечает за физическое хранение данных. Штатные бывают четырёх типов: `SQLite`, `Binary`, `XML` и `In-Memory`. Наиболее из них употребим – `SQLite`. Технически, можно создать свой класс хранилища, получающего данные от какого-нибудь веб-сервиса, подключить это хранилище в стэк `Core Data`, и работать с ним, как с обычным файлом `SQLite`. И такие [попытки](https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/1860108) были.

***Координатор***

[`NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html) связывает хранилище (или несколько хранилищ) с моделью данных и выдаёт и сохраняет данные по запросам привязанных к нему контекстов `NSManagedObjectContext`, организуя эти запросы в очередь.

В iOS 10 координатор поддерживает параллельное выполнение нескольких задач чтения плюс одну задачу записи. В системах до девятой включительно иногда имеет смысл держать несколько координаторов, подключенных к одному и тому же файлу `SQLite` (см. раздел о крупном импорте ниже).

***Пример***

Привожу простой код инициализации стэка в форме синглетона и связи главного и фонового контекстов:

DataSource.h

```
@interface DataSource : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext;

+ (instancetype)shared;

@end
```

DataSource.m

```
@interface DataSource ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext;

@end

@implementation DataSource

+ (instancetype)shared
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static id _singleton;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _singleton = [[self alloc] initInternal];
    });

    return _singleton;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    NSLog(@"Никаких alloc] init]! Используйте singleton [DataSource shared].");
    abort();
    return nil;
}

- (instancetype)initInternal
{
    self = [super init];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    // стэк Core Data
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    self.coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

    NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *storeURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *options = @{
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
    };

    NSPersistentStore *store = [self.coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];

    if (!store) {
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MY-OWN-ERROR-DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:@{
            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Не удалось подключить хранилище Core Data",
            NSUnderlyingErrorKey: error,
        }];
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    self.mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator;

    self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mainContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.mainContext];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.backgroundContext];

    return self;
}

- (void)mainContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        [self.backgroundContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}

- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.mainContext performBlock:^{
        [self.mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}

@end
```

#### Как получить данные

После того, как собран стэк, у него можно запрашивать существующие данные, создавать новые объекты и сохранять изменения.

[`NSFetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/) – это обращение к контексту, описывающее тип запрашиваемых объектов, критерии фильтрации, порядок сортировки и ещё довольно существенное количество гораздо менее широко известных параметров.

На уровне `NSPersistentStore` `SQLite`, например, типа, запрос транслируется в команды SQL и передаётся библиотеке `SQLite`.

Использовать запрос можно несколькими способами. Из общеупотребимых:

1. Попросить контекст выполнить этот запрос методом `-executeFetchRequest:error:`. В результате будет получен массив. В самом простом случае, при дефолтном `resultType == NSManagedObjectResultType`, этот массив будет содержать объекты `NSManagedObject`.
2. Попросить контекст посчитать количество объектов по этому запросу методом `-countForFetchRequest:error:`. Выполняется существенно быстрее за счёт того, что значения свойств не подгружаются, и объекты `NSManagedObject` не создаются.
3. Передать этот запрос `NSFetchedResultsController`. После выполнения `performFetch:` FRC получит объекты, соответствующие этому запросу. Если также указать делегата для FRC, то он будет непрестанно отслеживать изменения в контексте `NSManagedObjectContext`, и уведомлять делегата по протоколу `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` о произошедших изменениях в состоянии объектов.

Пункты 1 и 2 полезны при неких одноразовых действиях.

Пункт 3 используется для постоянной связки состояния данных с интерфейсом, `UITableView`, например.

#### Как посчитать агрегаты

Например, так:

```
- (void)calculateAggregateValues
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[DataSource shared] coordinator];

    [context performBlock:^{

        // наименование поставщика
        NSExpressionDescription *nameDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        nameDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"supplierName"];
        nameDescription.name = @"name";
        nameDescription.expressionResultType = NSStringAttributeType;

        // количество контрактов
        NSExpressionDescription *countDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        countDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"sumPlanned.@count"];
        countDescription.name = @"totalCount";
        countDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger32AttributeType;

        // планируемая сумма
        NSExpressionDescription *sumDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        sumDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.sumPlanned"];
        sumDescription.name = @"totalSum";
        sumDescription.expressionResultType = NSDoubleAttributeType;

        // запрос
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DBContract"];
        request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
        request.predicate =
            [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[
                [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"datePlanned < %@", [NSDate date]],
            ]];
        request.propertiesToFetch = @[nameDescription, countDescription, sumDescription];
        request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[nameDescription];

        // выполним запрос
        NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

        // возьмём объект с самой крупной суммой
        NSDictionary *values =
            [[result
                sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[
                    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"totalSum" ascending:NO],
                ]]
                firstObject];

        // покажем результаты в интерфейсе
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.nameLabel.text  = values[@"name"];
            self.countLabel.text = [values[@"totalCount"] stringValue];
            self.sumLabel.text   = [values[@"totalSum"] stringValue];
        });
    }];
}
```

Громоздко, но работает шустро. Почитать можно, например, [тут](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/core-data-queries-using-expressions/) или в [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html).

#### Зачем приложению несколько контекстов

Для разгрузки main thread. Как только появляется тяжёлая задача, и интерфейс начинает тормозить – задачу надо уводить в фон. Для случая с подсчётом агрегатов, например, создаётся `NSManagedObjectContext` с типом `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, в его `-performBlock:` выполняется задача, и полученные результаты передаются интерфейсу в main thread через `dispatch_async` (см. пример выше).

Случай с крупным импортом данных будет рассмотрен ниже.

#### Как реагировать на изменения в данных

Задача приложения обычно заключается в том, чтобы с как можно меньшими промедлениями синхронизировать интерфейс с состоянием данных. [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) специально создан для этой задачи: он отслеживает изменения в заданном наборе данных контекста и уведомляет о них своего делегата (`UIViewController`, например), который по получению этих уведомлений соответствующим образом обновляет интерфейс. Классическая связка `NSFetchedResultsController` с `UITableView` – [тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW26).

Альтернатива FRC – подписаться на уведомление `NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeNotification`, и самостоятельно разбирать полученный объект `NSNotification`.

#### Как не дать тормозить интерфейсу

Очень просто: оставить в нём только получение данных, которые увидит пользователь, и не грузить то, что пользователь, возможно, никогда и не увидит.

Для интерфейса чаще всего держат один общеприложенческий `NSManagedObjectContext` с типом конкуренции `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` – специально предназначенный для работы в main thread. Все `NSManagedObject`, данные из которых пойдут во всякие `UIlabel`, `UICollectionView`, `UITableView` и т.п. объекты интерфейсных классов, должны быть порождены таким контекстом, иначе придётся возиться с тем, что обращаться к свойствам объектов `NSManagedObject` можно только в потоке их контекста, а к элементам интерфейса – только в main thread.

Не грузить лишние данные – решается faultingом, batchingом и методами `estimatedRowHeight` для случая с различающимися по высоте строками таблицы. Например, в данных таблицы – две тысячи записей. Грузить их все сразу не имеет смысла, так как пользователь при первом показе таблицы увидит от силы тридцать строк. Данные оставшихся тысячи девятисот семидесяти объектов будут загружены зря, так как пользователь сразу лезет в поиск, и набор данных заново запрашиваются у `Core Data` со значительным сокращением по предикату, учитывающему строку пользовательского ввода.  Если не предоставить `UITableView` ожидаемую высоту строки, то после получения от делегата количества секций и объектов в секциях, таблице понадобится определить общую высоту своего контента, и она ринется вычислять (в случае с auto layout в строках) или требовать с делегата (в случае `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`) высоты каждой из двух тысяч строк. В обоих случаях это приведёт к подсчёту высоты строки для указанных ширины и атрибутов методом `-boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` – а это крайне дорогостоящий метод, выполняющийся на main thread. На нынешних аппаратах интерфейс зависнет секунд на пять, а то и больше, в зависимости от сложности ячеек.

#### Как вносить пользовательские изменения

Обычно пользователь генерирует поразительно мало изменений в данных. Возможны, конечно, ситуации типа "удалите все записи, полученные из БСЭ". Но чаще всего пользовательская активность ограничивается безумно долгим наколачиванием текста (при этом меняется одно свойство `text` объекта `DBMessage`), тапа по кнопке "лайк" (в связь "likedBy" объекта `DBMessage`добавляется один объект `DBPerson`) и тапу по кнопке "Отправить" (изменённый объект сохраняется, в фоне сериализуется и передаётся API веб-сервиса).

Подобную мелочь можно и нужно делать прямо в `mainContext`.

Создание и редактирование объектов бывает удобно делать на дочернем контексте, подключенном к `mainContext` и также имеющего тип `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. Например, тап по учётной карточке работника открывает в поповере `UIViewController`, который создаёт дочерний контекст, а в нём загружает указанный или создаёт новый объект `DBPerson`, данные которого раскидываются по вьюхам контроллера для просмотра и редактирования. Пользователь вносит свои изменения, тапает "Сохранить", дочернему контексту посылается `-save:`, изменения проталкиваются в `mainContext`, который тоже можно сразу сохранить, чтобы данные по цепочке `NSManagedObjectContext -> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator -> NSPersistentStore` попали бы в файл `SQLite`.

Если пользователь тапает "Отменить" – можно просто убрать контроллер, не сохраняя контекст. При этом изменения просто исчезнут вместе с ним.

#### Как делать крупный импорт

Небольшие изменения в данных можно проводить непосредственно на объектах `mainContext`. Но для внесения масштабных изменений в данные имеет смысл использовать фоновые контексты (`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`).

Жизнеспособной показала себя следующая схема:

- Процедура набивки данных ведётся в фоновом потоке. Тут удобно использовать `NSOperationQueue` – она поддерживает удобный механизм отмены исполнения её задач `NSOperation`.
- Для iOS вплоть до девятой версии следует использовать свой `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, привязанный к тому же файлу `SQLite`, что и координатор `mainContext`. Нужно это для того, чтобы избежать блокировки на уровне координатора – это медленная штука. Если пользователь начнёт крутить таблицу в тот момент, когда фоновый контекст пишет свои изменения, то интерфейс будет стоять, ожидая, пока общий координатор не закончит выполнять задачу фонового контекста. Два координатора на одном файле `SQLite` сводят общее время блокировки ко времени блокировки библиотеки `SQLite`, что существенно быстрее. Вот [тут](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/211/) это подробно разбирается, с 25:30.
- Разбор исходных данных надо делать пакетно, накапливая данные для нескольких тысяч объектов, чтобы система не убила приложение за жадность по потреблению памяти. Тут хорошо использовать что-то вроде `NSXMLParser` в режиме [SAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAX) и оборачивать в `@autoreleasepool` тела всех методов, участвующих в импорте..
- По достижению лимита пакета следует создать рабочий контекст, подключенный к своему координатору. В потоке этого контекста в методе `-performBlockAndWait:`насоздавать необходимые `NSManagedObject` или нафетчить существующие, наполнить их полученными данными, сохранить контекст и освободить его и данные пакета.
- Изменения, вносимые рабочим контекстом, надо передать в `mainContext`. Для этого:

  - Перед сохранением изменений рабочего контекста подписываемся на уведомление о его сохранении:

    ```
    - (void)processData
    {
        // создадим рабочий контекст
        NSManagedObjectContext *workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        workerContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator;

        [workerContext performBlockAndWait:^{

            // обрабатываем накопленные данные

            // подписываемся на уведомление о сохранении
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:workerContext];

            // сохраняем контекст
            NSError *error;

            if (![workerContext save:&error] {
                // обрабатываем ошибку
            }

            // отписываемся от уведомлений
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:workerContext];
        }];
    }
    ```
  - При сохранении рабочего контекста получаем уведомление, которое используем так:

    ```
    - (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        // сообщим о начале применения изменений
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DBWillUpdateDataNotification object:self];

        // mainContext
         NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[DataSource shared] mainContext];

        [mainContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];

        // сообщим об окончании применения изменений
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DBDidUpdateDataNotification object:self];
    }
    ```
  - В своих `UIViewController`ах следим за уведомлениями `DBWillUpdateDataNotification` и `DBDidUpdateDataNotification`. При начале обновлений отцепляем свои FRC от делегата `self.frc.delegate = nil;` (FRC не следит за изменениями в контексте без подключенного делегата). При окончании обновлений заново цепляем делегата к FRC, рефетчим FRC и статичные запросы, а потом обновляем интерфейс – перезагружаем таблицы, заполняем текстом метки и т.п.

  Такие пляски здорово решают две проблемы:

  1. При подтягивании изменений методом `-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` обновляются только те объекты, которые уже есть в обновляемом контексте. Созданные в рабочем контексте объекты не попадут в `mainContext`, о них ничего не узнают FRC, они не будут показаны в таблицах.
  2. Протаскивание всех изменений через FRC и анимация этих изменений в интерфейсе – добавление, удаление и изменение ячеек таблицы – очень ресурсоёмкий процесс. После нескольких пакетов интерфейс практически встанет.

#### Что с кэшированием

`Core Data` кэширует данные на нескольких уровнях.

1. `NSManagedObjectContext`, например, в ответ на запрос вернёт объекты, не обращаясь к своему координатору, если эти объекты уже ранее были им получены.
2. `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` держит row cache – сырые данные, полученные от `SQLite`, и при обращении к нему разных контекстов возвращает данные именно из этого кэша, не обращаясь к `SQLite`.
3. Ну и плюс у самой библиотеки `SQLite` есть свой собственный кэш.

#### Как отлаживать

Product / Scheme / Edit Scheme / Run / Arguments. В Arguments Passed On Launch добавить:

- `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` – включит лог запросов `Core Data` к `SQLite`.
- `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` – будет выкидывать exception при попытке доступа к свойствам `NSManagedObject` из не родного ему потока. Ловить exceptionы удобно так: View / Navigators / Show Breakpoint Navigator / кнопка с плюсом справа внизу / Add Exception Breakpoint… / Правой кнопкой по нему / Move Breakpoint To / User – и эта точка прерывания будет появляться во всех проектах.

Product / Profile / инструмент Core Data – подробно [тут](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/211/), там есть субтитры.

Comment: опять же из документации по `NSFetchedResultsController`: A fetch request. This must contain at least one sort descriptor to order the results.

Comment: Да, если использовать FRC. Для получения количества объектов – можно не использовать.

Comment: в вопросе вроде именно это и происходит

Comment: Задача – "необходимо получить количество". Зачем тут FRC?

Comment: посмотрите код в вопросе

Comment: Суть ответа как раз в том, что этот код избыточен.

Comment: Хочу вечером на маке попробовать ваши рекомендации. Я изначально пробовал через NSFetchRequest  без FRC. Но смущает такой момент - после добавления нового объекта в контекст методом insertNewObjectForEntityForName , и перед сохранением объектов в хранилище мой NSFetchRequest  возвращает  не 0 объектов (т.к. хранилище пустое), а 1 (тот который еще не сохранен). Я предполагаю что метод не смотрит в хранилище в, может, кэш

Comment: Так и должно быть. `NSFetchRequest` – это запрос состояния контекста, а не хранилища, что суть так и надо. Я тут немного дополнил ответ.

Comment: @bteapot  - спасибо , вы очень классно все разложили!!!!! я пытаюсь разобраться в CoreData и поэтому ваша информация очень помогла. было бы интересно почитать о синхронизации в контекстах, может если будет минута и вдохновение, - буду благодарен за общую инфу

Comment: Раз такое дело – "причесал" и дополнил ответ.